# Screenshot cron job not working

Tags: linux, cron, screenshot

I've been searching all over the internet for an aswer to this but can't seem to find anything that works for me.

I want to run a cron job that automaticly takes a screenshot every minute. The script look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ville/Skrivbord/screenshot
import -display :0 -win root screenshot.jpg
```

The code works fine when manually executed but does not work when i run it as a cron job.

The cron file look like this:

```
* * * * * /root/bin/screen.bash &> /dev/null
* * * * * /root/bin/syncdata.bash
```

The other task, syncdata works fine.

Here are some of the things i've tried without success:

Change permissions on /root/bin/screen.bash and /home/ville/Skrivbord/screenshot to 777 and change owner to root.

Change filename to screen.sh (maybe there's no difference between .bash and .sh?)

Change the import line to "import -win root screenshot.jpg" and "import -display :0.0 -win root screenshot.jpg".

Added the code:

```
# Set display to :0 if it's not already set.
: ${DISPLAY:=:0}
export DISPLAY
```

One time above the existing code in screen.bash and one time below.

Changed the line in cron to "* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /root/bin/screen.bash".

Nothing works!

Please help me

Comment: There is absolutely no difference in what the file name ends with. All that matters is the `#!` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs started by the *cron* daemon do not have the authentication data needed to connect to your X server. Try putting something like this in your `~/.xprofile`:

```
if [ "$XAUTHORITY" ]; then
    cp -f "$XAUTHORITY" ~/.Xauthority
fi
```

Comment: So i created a file /root/.xprofile and put the line there, but still no difference. Did i do it right?

By adding 2> /home/ville/Skrivbord/output.txt to the cron tab i got this:

    No protocol specified
    import: unable to open X server `:0' @ error/import.c   
    /ImportImageCommand/362.

Comment: @Vilhelm: No, it's not right. The script should be in *your* home directory (unless you for some unimaginable reason run X11 as root). If the cronjob is being run as a different user, you will have to modify the *xprofile* script to copy "$XAUTHORITY" to a location accessible by that user, and then edit your cron job to `export XAUTHORITY=<the new location>` accordingly.

Comment: @Vilhelm: Could you explain a bit more, in your original post, what *exactly* is all this supposed to achieve? (This seems too much like a "I want to know what my kids are browsing" kind of story.)

Comment: No this is supposed to be on a computer which controls two instuments for atmospheric measurements. The data from the graphs and terminal etc should be displayed on the instruents homepage for public view and for the scientist to be able to quickly check the status. I will try to put xprofiles in my home directory. But i actually run vrontab under root, I will try to run it under user to se if that works better! (but i allready have a crontab under root that works fine...)

Comment: Thank you so much grawity! I solved it by running crontab under user instead of root. Maybe the .xprofile file helped as well. Thank you!